# Fatal error: Cannot override final method

Tags: magento, fatal-error

Im pretty new in magento developing: just bought custom theme and after its installation I've got next message on account page:

> `Fatal error: Cannot override final method Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::clearInstance() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 39`

I didn't touch any core files. 
Could anyone tell me where to dig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seen this problem with APC before, add the following to your apc.ini

```
apc.include_once_override=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment,  but did you delete the var/cache directory via ftp? This function is assigned with a cache tag so I could see this being an issue.   If that has already been done do you have apc cache enabled?  If so maybe try restarting the web server.

Comment: Hi, the cache was cleared manually and in admin and there was no results.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as above (thanks JohnBoy I forgot about apc) but I believe you can add this per domain by doing this in the virtual host setup, saves applying to the global apc setup.

```
php_flag apc.include_once_override 0
```

Answer (score 0):

restarting apache cleaned this up for me, see post by Reedz here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/378965/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a situation (as I did) where apc.include_once_override=0 and restarting apache doesn't work, try disabling apc (I did it in httpd.conf) restarting apache and then re-enabling apc, this solved the problem. 
Not 100% why but guessing it caused some kind of flushing of the apc cache.